# Gas mixture algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have a pool of ten different gas mixtures.  Each gas mixture is made of nitrogen, oxygen and carbon dioxide in different percentages.

The goal is to mix and match sets of gasses to to get a requested percentage output.

Lets say we want 33-33-33 out.  Whats the best methodology to select the best subset of gases and mixing proportions to get an optimal output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solve 3 equations with 3 unknowns.

if mixture 1 has a1 fraction of chemical a (and similarly with other chemicals/mixtures), and you need xa : xb : xc mixture, where xa+xb+xc=1, this will be:

```
a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + a3 * x3 = xa
b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + b3 * x3 = xb
c1 * x1 + c2 * x2 + c3 * x3 = xc
```

Solve for x1, x2, x3. If you get negative numbers (or no solutions), this means that it's impossible to get the wanted mixture.

Comment: With 10 different gas mixtures you have 10 unknowns. I would suggest linear programming, in which case you can have non-negativity as constraints. For the objective function you can minimize a special variable V with constraints that V > (actual nitrogen - target nitrogen) and similar for all the other components. Given a constraint that all the proportions add up to 100% if you don't hit the target value at least one check will be > 0.

Comment: Seems I forgot some basic math.  Thanks for the reminder!